# How to add texture with CylinderGeometry

Tags: three.js

I looking for everywhere, but cannot find out how to add texture with CylinderGeometry, in this case hexagon.
This is my demo link

```
http://vi.anvyonline.com/test
```

I think i need 8 images (front, bottom, sides) to make it complete, am i right?
Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you need is a single image wrapped around the hexagon you don't need 8 images. Just use a texture map for the mesh which will repeat the image around the hexagon.

```
            var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "your-image.jpg" );
            /*
            //texture repeat and wrap properties http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Textures/Texture
            texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
            texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
            texture.repeat.set( 3, 3 );
            */
            var materials = [];
                materials.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
                        color: 0xff0000,
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                        map: texture
                    } ) );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I try your solution but the image is repeat itself.
You can go to http://vi.anvyonline.com/test to check.
Is there anyway to use image for the side faces?

Comment: For that i think you need to get the uv map. Calculate the points of the hexagon and assign image for that UV map. I will try to come up with code later.